# What is the difference between defining @Transactional on class vs method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

## Case1

```
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    ...................
    public void method1(){
        try{
            method2();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    public void method2(){

    }
}
```

## Case2

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    ...................
    public void method1(){
        try{
            method2();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    @Transactional
    public void method2(){

    }
}
```

In case1 if any exception occurs it rollback is working, but in case 2 it's not working. Is there any performance issues if I follow the case1?

Answer (score 144):

In case 1 @Transactional is applied to every public individual method. Private and Protected methods are Ignored by Spring.

> Spring applies the class-level annotation to all public methods of
>   this class that we did not annotate with @Transactional. However, if
>   we put the annotation on a private or protected method, Spring will
>   ignore it without an error.

In case 2 @Transactional is only applied to method2(), not on method1()

Case 1:
- Invoking method1() -> a transaction is started. When method1() calls method2() no new transaction is started, because there is already one

Case 2:
- Invoking method1() -> no transaction is started. When method1() calls method2() **NO** new transaction is started. This is because @Transactional does not work when calling a method from within the same class. It would work if you would call method2() from another class.

From the [spring reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.

Comment: To double up on the warning of invoking an annotated method from a non-annotated method: it does NOT start a transaction, even for the annotated method. See also mok's answer.

Answer (score 49):

`@Transactional`on a class applies to each method on the service. It is a shortcut. Typically, you can set `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on a service class, if you know that all methods will access the repository layer. You can then override the behavior with `@Transactional` on methods performing changes in your model. Performance issues between 1) and 2) are not known.

Comment: If I annotate a class Transactional(value="notPrimaryTransactionManager") and then annotate a member method with Transactional(readOnly=true), will the method use "notPrimaryTransactionManager" or will it use spring provided default transaction manager?

Answer (score 28):

Suppose you have the following class:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

  public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
    // do something
  }

  // these settings have precedence for this method
  @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

The `@Transactional` annotation on the class level will be applied to every method in the class.

*However*, when a method is annotated with `@Transactional` (like, `updateFoo(Foo foo)`) this will take precedence over the transactional settings defined at the class level.

More info:

- [Transaction management in Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: But only if updateFoo is called externally. If getFoo calls updateFoo (like the OP asked) then the complete transaction will be readonly.

Answer (score 21):

Quoting from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html)

> The Spring team's recommendation is that you only annotate concrete classes with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces.

Since this mechanism is based on proxies, only 'external' method calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that 'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!

Comment: This doesn't point the difference between `@Transactional` annotated method and `@Transactional` annotated class.

Comment: @kocko> I thought the OP will follow the link, nevertheless I've just updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @mok I was facing the "self-invocation won't create a transaction" problem and this answer made me remind the learning I had some time back. Thank you!

Comment: This does not explain the difference the OP was asking, but only highlights a gotcha with annotating the methods with ```@Transactional```. The linked documentation is now updated. For posterity's sake, the latest documentation says: _The Spring team recommends that you annotate only concrete classes **(and methods of concrete classes)** with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces._