# Spring transactions - required new - rollback for parent

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a service which do some work:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

  @Override
  public void invoke() { 
      process();
  }

  public void process() {

    // possible that will throw exception
    elements.forEach -> processOne(..)

  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void processOne(..) {

  // possible that will throw exception

  }
```

}

The `invoke()` method is called from another component. As I understand this method is running within transaction (if exist - continute, if not - create new one). But what I expected - method `processOne(..)` is running in new transaction - so if in this one everything is ok transaction should be commited. But if error occur then whole process is rolled back. Not only from current transaction. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

processOne method call will not create a new transaction when it is called from the same class, only if it is called directly from an other class.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132822/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-transactional-on-class-vs-method/23133160#23133160) and my answer on it.

From the [spring reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.