# Is Spring @Service transactional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

When I am on a spring service and I want to update several database tables through spring repositories, do I need to add @Transactional to make sure I am transactional and rollback or is it already there?
If yes, do I need to add it to the class level or method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you need to add it separately. For more details, please refer:

[What is the difference between defining @Transactional on class vs method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132822/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-transactional-on-class-vs-method)

and

[Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background)

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained