# No transaction behaviour needed in Spring Data

Tags: spring-transactions

I am trying to figure it out how to configure a method not to run within a transaction using Spring. I have read that the Spring Data repositories by default activate the transactional behaviour in its methods. I dont want this transaction because I have many "save" calls to a repository and each of them is independent from the other. I think creating a transaction for each call to a repository method can slow down the code and the performance of the app.  So :

- Is this possible or every service or dao method has to run within a transaction?
- If it has, why?
- If this is possible, how to configure a method not to run within a transaction? Just removing the Spring transactional annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring service beans by default are not transactional. You can add the @Transactional at a class or a method level to force it to be transactional. Here  are a few links explaining in detail on how transactional in Spring works.
[What is the difference between defining @Transactional on class vs method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132822/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-transactional-on-class-vs-method) .
[Spring - @Transactional - What happens in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099025/spring-transactional-what-happens-in-background) .
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained .

It is also discussed in the below thread .
[Is Spring @Service transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833029/is-spring-service-transactional/50833103)

Comment: But what about Spring Data repositories?. They are transactional annotated by default. How to override this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, Spring Repositories add transactional behaviour by default to all crud queries. I am not entirely sure about the approach, i can suggest two solutions. One is to override the crud methods and exclude the @Transactional annotation, Two is to create a separate/new method which saves the data. Custom methods are not transactional by default inside a repository. Have a look at the answer from the below thread . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827054/spring-jpa-repository-transactionality