# Why changes is not reflected in database while updating in spring scheduler?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-scheduled

**My changes are not reflected in the database. I am trying to do changes to this TasksScheduler class. But no changes are reflected in the database. If I do:**

```
System.out.println(bannerRepo.save(banner))
```

Then it is showing output. But no database changes happen. But if I try to save or delete outside scheduler class then changes happens. My TasksScheduler class:

```
package com.shopKpr.apps.medicine.repositories.admin.jpa;

import com.shopKpr.apps.medicine.model.admin.Banner;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
@Slf4j
@EnableScheduling
public class TasksScheduler {

    private final BannerRepo bannerRepo;

    public TasksScheduler( BannerRepo bannerRepo ) {
        this.bannerRepo = bannerRepo;
    }

    //sec, min, hour
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 14 3 * * *", zone = "Asia/Dacca") //Schedule at night 1 AM
    public void schedulerTask() {
        updateOfferState();
    }


    @Transactional
    void updateOfferState() {

        java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

        List<Banner> bannerList = bannerRepo.findAll();

        bannerList.parallelStream()
                .filter(banner -> today.after(banner.getBannerStartDate()))
                .forEach(banner -> {
                    banner.setEnabled(true);
                    bannerRepo.save(banner);
                });

        List<Banner> deletableBanners = bannerList.stream()
                .filter(banner -> today.after(banner.getBannerEndDate()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        deletableBanners.forEach(banner -> bannerRepo.deleteById(banner.getBannerId()));


    }
}
```

My Banner class:

```
package com.shopKpr.apps.medicine.model.admin;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table
@Entity
public class Banner implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long bannerId;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy", timezone = "Asia/Dhaka")
    private Date bannerStartDate;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy", timezone = "Asia/Dhaka")
    private Date bannerEndDate;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String bannerImage;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    private String hyperLinkId;
}
```

Banner repository:

```
package com.shopKpr.apps.medicine.repositories.admin.jpa;

import com.shopKpr.apps.medicine.model.admin.Banner;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BannerRepo extends JpaRepository<Banner, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Where do you have the transactional annotation?

Comment: If I do a transaction then the result is also the same....

Comment: No changes in database

Comment: Update happens outside of TaskScheduler class but not in TaskScheduler

Comment: Either have the transactional annotation on top of your scheduler class or move your update method to another class and keep the transactional annotation on top of your updateOfferState method.

Comment: Didn't work......

Comment: Please add the transactional annotation in your question as well. Because without which it doesn't work right?

Comment: Updated...can you please check?

Comment: Checked, you see it won't work, because you have transactional on a private method. Put it on top of the Scheduler class. Or 
 move the update method to another class and keep the transactional annotation on top of your updateOfferState method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132822/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-transactional-on-class-vs-method

Comment: no luck so far......tried both way :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and landed on your post.

I managed to resolve mine by simply adding @Transactionnal on top of my scheduler class (in your case, `TaskScheduler`)

I know I'm a bit late, but I hope it will help other people